# Vector swap data

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a problem with a vector. 
I have this vector e.g. `[1 4 19 32 5 6 9 1]` and I want to mirror the `v(3)-v(6)` (`v` is the vector's name). I want to have this:
`[1 4 6 5 32 19 9 1]`
I'm using matlab but i don't know how to do this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mirror a vector, `v` from indices `a` to `b` do this `v(a:b) = fliplr(v(a:b))`.

**Edit**: If `v` is a column vector, use `v(a:b) = flipud(v(a:b))`

Comment: It is better to use `flip` rather than `fliplr` just in case `v` is a column vector.

Comment: No need for a function: `v(a:b) = v(b:-1:a);`